# Norm of a arrays of vectors in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, norm

I have this array

```
   A = array([[-0.49740509, -0.48618909, -0.49145315],
   [-0.48959259, -0.48618909, -0.49145315],
   [-0.49740509, -0.47837659, -0.49145315],
   ..., 
   [ 0.03079315, -0.01194593, -0.06872366],
   [ 0.03054901, -0.01170179, -0.06872366],
   [ 0.03079315, -0.01170179, -0.06872366]])
```

which is a collection of 3D vector. I was wondering if I could use a vectorial operation to get an array with the norm of each of my vector.

I tried with `norm(A)` but it didn't work.

Comment: yes, is it relevant to what I've asked?

Comment: I think it is yes. [`numpy.array`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) is different from the [`array`](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html) class in Python. I assume that you want answers related to `numpy.array`?

Comment: FYI: In the next release of numpy (1.8.0), you will be able to use the `axis` argument: `norm(A, axis=1)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Doing it manually might be fastest (although there's always some neat trick someone posts I didn't think of):

```
In [75]: from numpy import random, array

In [76]: from numpy.linalg import norm

In [77]: 

In [77]: A = random.rand(1000,3)

In [78]: timeit normedA_0 = array([norm(v) for v in A])
100 loops, best of 3: 16.5 ms per loop

In [79]: timeit normedA_1 = array(map(norm, A))
100 loops, best of 3: 16.9 ms per loop

In [80]: timeit normedA_2 = map(norm, A)
100 loops, best of 3: 16.7 ms per loop

In [81]: timeit normedA_4 = (A*A).sum(axis=1)**0.5
10000 loops, best of 3: 46.2 us per loop
```

This assumes everything's real.  Could multiply by the conjugate instead if that's not true.

Update: Eric's suggestion of using `math.sqrt` won't work -- it doesn't handle numpy arrays -- but the idea of using sqrt instead of `**0.5` is a good one, so let's test it.

```
In [114]: timeit normedA_4 = (A*A).sum(axis=1)**0.5
10000 loops, best of 3: 46.2 us per loop

In [115]: from numpy import sqrt

In [116]: timeit normedA_4 = sqrt((A*A).sum(axis=1))
10000 loops, best of 3: 45.8 us per loop
```

I tried it a few times, and this was the largest difference I saw.

Comment: `**0.5` will always be slower than `math.sqrt`

Answer (score 2):

just had the same prob, maybe late to answer but this should help others.
You can use the **axis** argument in the norm function

```
norm(A, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about [this method](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html)?
Also you might want to add a [numpy] tag to the post.

Comment: Initially I thought you couldn't find the `linalg.norm` method as you said norm(A)  "didn't work", but after reading Eric's answer I guess it's more likely that you did try `linalg.norm` but it didn't give you what you wanted.

Comment: @JoelCornett: As a result of the OP being vague with "it didn't work". He might have explained what he tried and how it didn't work. Like I explained in my comment above.

Comment: You're right. This is more of a case of OP being obscure. Redacted.

Answer (score 0):

Having never used numpy, I'm going to guess:

```
normedA = array(norm(v) for v in A)
```

Comment: `map(norm, A)` might be faster in this situation.

Comment: @Joel: Yeah, but it doesn't return a numpy array, so you'd at least have to wrap it in `np.array()`

Comment: @Matteo What about if I use it as a generator?

Comment: @Matteo: what size is your dataset and how slow is it?

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work as written: it will give something like `array(<generator object <genexpr> at 0x102d88f50>, dtype=object)`.  You'd need to use `fromiter`, I think.